# How to click an <option> element with WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, ui-automation

This is a piece of UI code

```
<select id="order_unit_line_rate_806782_is_addenda_enabled" class="selects_for_487886" onchange="select_addendum(806782, this);dateShowMemory(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, '806782');" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / drop down" name="order_unit_line_rate[806782][is_addenda_enabled]">
     <option value="0" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / Fee">                     Fee                   </option>
     <option value="1" uniqueattr="Dynamic Site Accelerator / Dynamic Site Accelerator / Additional Usage Commitment / See Attached Addendum">                     See Attached Addendum                   </option>
</select>
```

where the `<option>` tags are nested inside the `<select>` tag. I need to `click()` on the second `<option>` element which is an item in the dropdown list. The dropdown is clickable when i try to `click()` on the `<select>` tag using id / uniqueattr.

How do I traverse the `<option>` tags nested under `<select>` and click on the right item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will select the option with value "1" in the select with id "order_unit_line_rate_806782_is_addenda_enabled".

```
Select select = (Select)webdriver.findElement(By.id("your id here"));
select.selectByValue("1");
```

You can also select by index or text; [see the docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html).

Comment: Thanks for quick response Qwerky :) .. But i get this error when i do what you said. `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`, do i need to select a different "Select" ... ?

Comment: @KiranKoundinya Yep, it's an easily discoverable typo by Qwerky, should be `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.anything("tudumtudum")));`

Answer (score 10):

Besides the correct Qwerky's answer, you can also do simple

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[@value='1']")).click();
```

This finds the `option` element with `value='1'` and clicks it, practically selecting it in the drop-down.

Both mine and Qwerky's solution are described and [explained here, in the documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#user-input-filling-in-forms).

Comment: Thanks for quick response Slanec:) .. But i get this error when i do what you said. `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select`, do i need to select a different "Select" ... ?

Comment: As is stated in the link I posted as well as in the one Qwerky posted (oh, c'mon, really), you should do `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.anything("tudumtudum")));`

Comment: yup i tried the same meanwhile i got the reply :) .. it worked.. Thanks a million  - @Slanec :)

Comment: Just want I needed. Thanks!