# How to select value from dropdown using java (selenium web driver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I need to select a value from dropdown can some one help me on that. Html part is below

```
<div id="element11_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 320px;">
<a class="chzn-single" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0">
<div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 318px; top: 29px;">
<div class="chzn-search">`enter code here`
<ul class="chzn-results">
<li id="element11_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">ActiveLearn Course</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">ActiveLearn Player</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_3" class="active-result result-selected" style="">ActiveLearn Skin</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">ActiveLearn Template</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">Activity</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">Animation</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">Assessment</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">Bookmarks</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_9" class="active-result" style="">Character</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_10" class="active-result" style="">Click to prompt</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_11" class="active-result" style="">Click to prompt override</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_12" class="active-result" style="">EBook</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_13" class="active-result" style="">Exercise</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_14" class="active-result" style="">Game</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_15" class="active-result" style="">Glossary</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_16" class="active-result" style="">Glossary Term</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_17" class="active-result" style="">Glossary Term</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_18" class="active-result" style="">Imported file</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_19" class="active-result" style="">Interactive activity</li>
<li id="element11_chzn_o_20" class="active-result" style="">Interactive page</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I have to make it dynamic so I need to get the value from xls.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343017/how-to-click-an-option-element-with-webdriver

Comment: This would help you http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/04/Select.html

Comment: Have you guys read the code?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you :

```
Select select = new Select(yourDropdownElement);
select.selectByVisibleText(text);
```

Comment: This won't work, because it is not a <input type="select" button>

Comment: I have got this error org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Element cannot be scrolled into view:[object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not using actually a  element, i'd use the following code that should suit perfectly in that scenario. That should click in case a element finds the correct text inside the `<li>` element.

```java
public void selectValueFromUnorderedList(WebElement unorderedList, final String value) {
    List<WebElement> options = unorderedList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement option : options) {
        if (value.equals(option.getText())) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this method, all you need to do send the proper `WebElement` and the String you're looking to find. Say you need to get *Game*, in your scenario that's easy as:

```java
WebElement ul = driver.findElement(By.className("chzn-results"));
selectValueFromUnorderedList(ul, "Game");
```

And, *voilà*! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ul = document.getElementById("chzn-results");
var liArray = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length; i++) {
     {
        //where liArray[i] being the LI element on the position (i) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element11_chzn")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("element11_chzn_o_7")).click(); /*It will select 'Assessment' from drop down.*/
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sample program to get value from drop down :

```
public class demo {


       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


       FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //OPEN SPECIFIC URL IN BROWSER
        driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");


       //SELECT SPECIFIC VALUE FROM DROPDOWN
       Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("continents")));
       sel.selectByVisibleText("Australia");

        }
   }
```

Comment: Please note that we expect answers to address the *specific* issues in the question. If you have a very relevant alternative, you *can* consider adding that - but please be sure to address the question and explain exactly why, first.

Answer (score 0):

Sample statements to open browser, load URL and select value from dropdown

```
static WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\(Path)\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("EnterURLHere");          
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Select value1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("element11_chzn")));    
value1.selectByVisibleText("Character");    //Select Character from dropdown list
```